# Oracle locked sessions with ASP.Net

Tags: oracle-10g, locking, session

I am connecting to an Oracle database in ASP.Net using SQLDataSource. My connection string is:

```
<add name="ConnectionString3"
 connectionString="Data Source=sml; User ID=sml; Password=sml; Unicode=True; Pooling=False;"
 providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
```

Problem is that when I look at `v$session` on the database, I can see two locked sessions. They don't clear till I shutdown the ASP.Net server.

i.e. the query

```
select * 
from v$session b
where status='INACTIVE' and schemaname='SML' AND program='w3wp.exe'
```

always shows two sessions which don't clear till I shutdown the server.

What is the proper way in ASP.Net to connect with an Oracle database and then manage the connections to clear after connecting with database? I meant how can I logout from the database after querying it?

Are there any session settings to do in the Oracle database?

Comment: What does it mean to you to have a "locked session"?  What query are you running and what results are you seeing that leads you to believe that there is a problem?

Comment: I am Just selecting Data from DB using Sqldatasource

Comment: And there are permanently loacked sessions in session browser

Comment: What is a "permanently locked session"?  That's not a term I've ever come across so I'm very unsure what you're seeing and why you believe what you are seeing is problematic.

Comment: Ok Sir Tell me One Thing...If we connect with oracle database from asp.net or any other platform then there become a session which tell us the host which database is connected and then also we close the connection after connecting with DB to Clear that session from DB.I am Doing selecting and also closing the DB connection then why there is locked session in session browser of Oracle DB

Comment: Again, what is a "locked session"?  I still don't understand what that term means to you.

Comment: Sir I meant this `select * from v$session b
where status='INACTIVE'
and schemaname='SML'
AND PROGRAM='w3wp.exe'` here are two permanent sessions which don't clear till i shutdown the server